# What is the easiest way to read and plot coordinates from an airfoil coordinates file?

Tags: python, string, list

I have downloaded an airfoil from [Airfoil Tools](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=k2-il). I want to load it into Python to plot it and make some calculations from the geometry.

Edit: [example file](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/seligdatfile?airfoil=b29tip-il)

To read the file I've tried using this:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
```

However I encountered many problems because the data is a string so I have to manually convert types and delete columns and such. Is there an easier way to do this? What I want is flexibility to access and manipulate the data.

Comment: Your question must be self-contained ([ask]), so please [edit] it to include a sample of the file you want to parse. IME these files are usually comma (or other character)-delimited files with a few headers that might need to be ignored, and there are _lots_ of questions addressing how to read these files on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really embrace Python libraries to perform certain tasks for which code is already tested and neatly packaged into a library. For your purposes (importing data, array manipulation and operations and plotting) libraries such as [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html), [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) and Matplotlib are very common and powerful, there are a bunch of resources on it's capabilities. I really recommend you to check out their websites:

On Airfoil tools you can directly [download](https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/goe383.dat) a `.dat` file which you can import directly using pandas. Then using simple parameters declared when calling your function will correctly parse the data and return it in the appropriate data type (`float` instead of `str`).

Code Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


filename = 'airfoil.dat' #enter your file path here
data = pd.read_table(filename,delim_whitespace=True,skiprows=[0],names=['x','y'],index_col=False)

#Plot
plt.plot(data.x, data.y, 'r',marker='.',markeredgecolor='black', markersize=3)
plt.plot(0.5*data.x+0.3,0.5*data.y) #Scale & translate the datapoints

#Plot settings
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim((-0.05, 1.05))
plt.legend(['GOE 383 AIRFOIL','SCALED AIRFOIL'])
```

[image: Airfoil Plots]

Comment: That's very nice. Thank you. How can I do this multiple times for multiple files?

Comment: I suppose you could call each file within a loop. You could check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)